# How to get physical conversion rate from mdf4

Tags: python, mdf, asammdf

How can I extract the conversion factor and offset for the signals of an mdf4 file. I am using asammdf, but I couldn't figure out, from where it gets the information e.g. when I use the `mdf.to_dataframe(raw=False)` method.

Answer (score 0):

This information cannot be aprt of the dataframe.
Instead you should extract just the required channel and look at the conversion attribute

```
from asammdf import MDF
m = MDF(file)
ch = m.get('MySignal', raw=True)
print(ch.conversion)
```